# mongodb sharding of shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Currently I run a mongodb replicaset and this db is growing too fast.
My collection is a called Reading with metering_point_id, timestamp, power and energy, where metering_point_id is the id of the smartmeter.

Every second a smartmeter is sending a new record to the mongodb. The number of smartmeters is also growing.

I need a scalable mongodb infrastructure.
I think with mongodb sharding is possible.
My ideal scenario might look like.

- shard1 metering_point_id from 1 to 100

  - subshard2013 timestamp from start 2013 to end 2013
  - subshard2014 timestamp from start 2014 to end 2014
  - ... and so on
- shard2 metering_point_id from 101 to 200

  - subshard2013 timestamp from start 2013 to end 2013
  - subshard2014 timestamp from start 2014 to end 2014
  - ... and so on
- ... and so on

like this: https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/1533835d-05ce-4d5d-b719-fe94b4f84db6

is this possible with mongodb? this sub sharding thing?

many thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about several machines?

Comment: yes and each shard is a replicaset with 3 server

Comment: I think you can only use one key, The documentation says: "The index on the shard key cannot be a multikey index."

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you just add a shard and have the balancer do the rest?

Comment: i think compound-shard-key the solution. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/#shard-using-a-compound-shard-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a rigid hierarchy within your shards is not important you can use compound shard keys to shard the data. You can use the below command to create the compound shard keys

`sh.shardCollection("<smartmeter_db>", {"metering_point_id" : 1, "timestamp" : 1})`